# What would happen to the Moon if the Earth stopped providing it with a centripetal force owing to its force of gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, solar-system, celestial-mechanics

Would the Moon really only travel in a straight line then? What about the *other* planets and their forces of gravity? Wouldn't they prevent this rectilinear and undisturbed motion of the Moon?

Comment: There is no such thing as a centripetal force.  There is something called centripetal acceleration, which just describes a very specific type of acceleration, namely that of circular curves.  The only macroscopic forces present in the Earth-moon system are gravity, radiation pressure (very weak), and particle pressure (almost non-existent from dust and solar wind particles).

Answer (score 4):

If the Earth just disappeared, the Moon would continue around the Sun on pretty much the same path it has now.

To see this, consider the velocity of the Earth/Moon system around the Sun:

$2\pi \times 150 \times 10^6 \text{ km} / 365 \text{ days} = 2.6 \times 10^6 \text{ km}/\text{day}$

versus the Moon's speed around the Earth:

$2\pi \times 385 \times 10^3 \text{ km} / 29 \text{ days} = 83 \times 10^3 \text{ km}/\text{day}$

The motion around the Sun is a factor of $30$ faster; the Moon's motion around the Earth is just a small perturbation on that.